# How do I represent other languages in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, text, utf-8

I have tried to represent text in the website.

However, that text is pulled from the HTML results returned by the Perl. So it is already in UTF-8. The English text shows up just fine but, Thai text doesn't show up right.

This is the Thai text that I stored in the database

http://windu.cpe.kmutt.ac.th/cgi-bin/Devel/SeniorProjectAssistant.pl?action=getabstract&projectid=88&english_flag=false&projectyear=2559

Set the encoding to UTF-8 and you will see Thai text in the correctly rendered.

but the output I got is not as I expect

[image: Click here to see the output]

As you can see the English text is correct, but the Thai text is not.

This is the code that I use to pull data from database;

```
function getAbstract_API(projectYear,projectId,english_flag,successfunction, errorfunction)
{
var requestString = url + "?action=getabstract&projectyear=" + projectYear;
requestString += "&projectid=" + projectId + "&english_flag=" + english_flag;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("Get",requestString);
request.send(null);
// Register a handler to take care of the data on return
request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
    if (request.readyState == 4)
        {           
        if (request.status == 200) 
            {
            // If we get here, we got a complete valid HTTP response
            var response = request.responseText;
            var errorpattern = /\w*ERROR/;
            if (response.match(errorpattern))
                {
                var errcode = extractErrorCode(response);
                var messagedetail = getMessageDetail(errcode);
                showI18NAlert(messagedetail);
                if (errorfunction)
                    errorfunction();
                return false;
                }
            alert(response);

            if (successfunction)
                successfunction();
            }
        else
            {
            showI18NAlert('requesterror_msg');
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

I use `alert(response)` to check the result and the English is fine, Thai is not. So I assume it must be some mistake in this step.

Anybody have any idea how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting and what you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your Perl program sends the data not utf-8 encoded. If you look at the header, you'll see that it's Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 08:14:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I don't know how you create that output. If it's [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod), you just need to change your header to include the correct encoding string. It might look something like this.

```
print $cgi->header(
    -type       => 'text/html',
    -charset    => 'utf-8',
);
```

---

You also do not send a complete HTML document. Your document structure is like this.

```
<h3>
...
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

There is stuff missing. That's not related to the problem, but it could give you other problems. If all you want to do is get text, consider switching your response to `text/plain` and remove the HTML entirely, or just use `application/json` and wrap it in a JSON object.